# How to delete save data from a iOS application

Tags: ios, save, archive, nscoder

I'm developing an IOS App, and I'm currently working on archiving the data with NSCoder, but I had initially saved the wrong data type to a variable, and now its causing my application to crash, I have fixed the problem that was saving the wrong data, but I now need to delete that corrupted save data.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the app from the device and re-installing it? All of the app's files are contained in its package.

Comment: I should clarify this is all on the simulator, but ill try deleting it off the simulator

Comment: that worked! thank you, If you repost as an answer I'll click it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data is stored inside the app package. Try deleting the app and re-installing it.

Comment: In this case it's stored in the App Sandbox, not the app package. Data and resources built and added to an app at compile time are added to the app __bundle__, but data saved at runtime is added to the app __sandbox__

Comment: Hmm... It is my understanding that the .app folder is called a package. I could be wrong, but regardless, the data is stored in it.